# implementing dlib pyramid_up with cv_image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, dlib

I'm trying to use dlib's function pyramid_up on an open cv Mat image wrapped with the cv_image wrapper from the dlib library as so..

```
cv::Mat & src

cv_image<rgb_pixel> cimg(src);

pyramid_up(cimg);
```

the `cv::Mat` and `dlib::cv_image` work well together similarly a `dlib::array2d<rgb_pixel>` works well with `dlib::pyramid_up`. However, when used in combination i get a list of errors from dlibs interpolation.h which all say `could not deduce template argument for..`

any ideas?

edit: This question was so long ago I cannot remember the intended purpose so cannot say if the solutions work. Teresa's advice seems solid though, attempt this if found in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Did you manage to solve it? I successfully use pyramid_up like this:

```
cv::Mat & src
array2d<bgr_pixel> img;
assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(src));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**pyrUp**](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gada75b59bdaaca411ed6fee10085eb784) OpenCV function instead. It looks similar.. Here is some ref: [**OpenCv 3.0 tutorials**](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html).

Comment: Please provide the essential informations from the external resource you point.. Links can die easily.

Answer (score 0):

// I test it ok and pass

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/time.h>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>  
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"  
#include "dlib/opencv.h"  
#include "dlib/array2d.h"  
#include "dlib/image_io.h"  
#include "dlib/image_processing.h"  
#include "dlib/image_transforms.h"  
#include "dlib/gui_widgets.h"  
using namespace cv;  
using namespace dlib;  

typedef scan_fhog_pyramid<pyramid_down<6>> image_scanner_type;  

int main(void)  
{  
    Mat                                 src_bgr;  
    object_detector<image_scanner_type> detector;  
    array2d<bgr_pixel>                  img2d;  
    std::vector<dlib::rectangle>        dlib_rects;  
    image_window                        iwin;  

    std::ifstream svmbase("./detector.svm", std::ios::binary);
    deserialize(detector, svmbase);

    //load_image(img2d, "./uschwaa2.png");
    //pyramid_up(img2d);
    src_bgr = imread("./uschwaa2.png");         //same as load_image
    cv::resize(src_bgr,src_bgr,Size(256,256));  //same as pyramid_up assume original 128 x 128

    assign_image(img2d, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(src_bgr));
    dlib_rects = detector(img2d);

    iwin.clear_overlay();
    iwin.set_image(img2d);
    iwin.add_overlay(dlib_rects, rgb_pixel(255,0,0));

    usleep(3000000);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i've used this code to overcome this problem

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to connect to camera" << endl;
        getchar();
    }
cv::Mat temp;
cap.read(temp);
cv::imwrite("img/Latest.jpg", temp); // saving image to folder using openCV
matrix<rgb_pixel> test2;
load_image(test2, "img/Latest.jpg");
pyramid_up(test2);
```

it worked for me, the idea is saving the image and load it again as `matrix<rgb_pixel>`  so the `pyramid_up()` can handle with it .

Note: if you run the recognition in real time video, i don't think this will be helpful.